# How to send cookies with HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, cookies

I am trying to set the cookies in a post request for a site login. On page load it sends 2 cookies, which needs to be forwarded along side with the form data and random token. The issue is when I try to send the cookies they are not sent along with the request from what I can see. I have watched the traffic in fiddler and am able to login with fiddler get and post requests, but for some reason when I send the post request it is not taking the cookies I pass. Is there something I am doing wrong? Essentially BNIPERSISTENCE is one cookie recieved when sending the get request and HEADERTOKEN is the second. I extract the data and send

GET Response headers in fiddler

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:108d6c40-8e9b-4193-a846-0c576b7332c7
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Request-Context
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Sat, 29 Feb 2020 12:33:14 GMT
Set-Cookie: BNI_persistence=Klo3qdYxHhTajTvX2rs4mlsa1XHF0WaExapcBZmI9_giCrGal8nbxidBqscFEtD9HSM4jJ11uKWOcNLtT3==; Path=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Set-Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=SV4ZgxwyEtLisMJAJjbno6P-A-QXADPFnjoo8_79rqr0i7TCAOog8ar_vBF9n3A__qjYF75nEl7MD8uSre9UXR1WaobF60xVeGWqXt; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 29169
```

Post Request in fiddler

```
POST https://www.example.com/SignIn HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 218
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://www.example.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Referer: https://www.example.com/signin
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: BNI_persistence=Klo3qdYxHhTajTvX2rs4mlsa1XHF0WaExapcBZmI9_giCrGal8nbxidBqscFEtD9HSM4jJ11uKWOcNLtT3==; __RequestVerificationToken=SV4ZgxwyEtLisMJAJjbno6P-A-QXADPFnjoo8_79rqr0i7TCAOog8ar_vBF9n3A__qjYF75nEl7MD8uSre9UXR1WaobF60xVeGWqXt
```

Post Response  in fiddler Gives the final authentication token needed to signin

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:108d6c40-8e9b-4193-a846-0c576b7332c7
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Request-Context
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Sat, 29 Feb 2020 12:36:11 GMT
Content-Length: 118
Set-Cookie: BNI_persistence=Klo3qdYxHhTajTvX2rs4mlsa1XHF0WaExapcBZmI9_giCrGal8nbxidBqscFEtD9HSM4jJ11uKWOcNLtT3==; Path=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Set-Cookie: AuthenticatedBuyerToken=41a28507-3010-4d0d-ae6c; path=/; secure; HttpOnly

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Data sent in the post request

```
__RequestVerificationToken=kifbio0JkXHE6H0nu_HTS-dEFzXyOxovbkqa0B-Uywywim5NCWgenAY3wr_Cn669insTMC8-xA7-HYLqBFiMe9c7CpXK&Username=username&Password=pass&Remember=false&login-submit=Log+In
```

My Post Request is the the issue. I do not get a 301, I get a 200 with the same response pretty much as the first get response in fiddler.

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // Acts like a browser
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Host", "example.com");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "218");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Origin", "https://www.example.com");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.addRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "https://www.example.com/signin");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");

    conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie",  BNIPERSISTENCE+ "; " + HEADERTOKEN);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

// Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = 
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

        for (String header : conn.getHeaderFields().keySet()) {
   if (header != null) {
     for (String value : conn.getHeaderFields().get(header)) {
        System.out.println(header + ":" + value);
      }
   }
```

When I send the request in java I receive a status `200` instead of `301`. It returns a peace of the cookie that was in the headers but not the right value. It returns only request session token So the issue has to either be with how I am passing cookies or how I am sending the body?

Comment: 301 means the server said, your endpoint is not correct, you have to use a different endpoint. Make sure the URL you use to post is correct.

Comment: I don't get a 301 when I send via java. The 301 you see here is from my successful request via Fiddler not java.

Comment: Also a 301 means a permanent redirect not a server endpoint error. That would be 5xx.. In the case of my fiddler requests a 301 means the page has moved from /signin to / indicating that it is logged in.

Comment: I did not mean an error from server. If you are not getting 301, then what do you get in Java?

Comment: I'm getting  200 but should be getting a 301